# Weird keyboard behaviour by Emacs in a terminal

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, terminal-emacs

I am having problems to configure my `EMACS` in `-nw` mode using linux thorough `ssh`. I am trying to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to **redo** using *undo-tree-redo*. I tried the following code

```
(defalias 'redo 'undo-tree-redo)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'undo)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-z") 'redo)
```

I also want to map some other key bindings using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, however, it seems that it is not mapped correctly. I tried to follow this solution [Shift+Up isn't recognized by Emacs in a terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/977/shiftup-isnt-recognized-by-emacs-in-a-terminal). However when I try to get the escape function to say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, it returns `^Z`, which is exactly the same as whiotu the shift key!!!!

So the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key has absolutly no effect on the key binding. The shift key does work though, since I can use it to capitalize etc.

How can I solve this issue?

Note: some other keys also have a weird behaviour when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to insert the characters literally. For instance the <kbd>return</kbd> key gives `^M` and the <kbd>backspace</kbd> gives `^?`. I have absolutely no idea what's going on!

Comment: Just a few days ago, I answered [essentially the same question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18316/the-shift-is-useless-when-i-am-in-the-iterm2-with-emacs-nw) only to learn that it had been asked and answered before. I am smelling a FAQ …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, C-z and C-S-z are the same when inside of a terminal; the terminal protocol simply provides no way to distinguish between them. The terminal only deals in characters, not keypresses, so there's no way for the other end to know what modifier keys were in use, only what character was generated.

Since I presume you're running Emacs over ssh in order to edit files on the remote host, I recommend that you run Emacs locally instead, and edit the files over ssh using TRAMP mode. Simply type in a remote filename when you open a file: `C-x f /user@otherhost:path/to/file RET`.

BTW, you can figure out what's going on by looking at a chart of the [ASCII control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart). `C-q RET` produces ^M because that's the carriage return character, and `C-q DEL` produces ^? because that's the delete character. They're displayed as ^M and ^? because they're not normally displayed at all.

Comment: Using TRAMP mode works like a charm! Thank you!